# How to check if symbol is T?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am doing some text processing, part of it is splitting words into single characters. Every character gets interned as a symbol in upper case with some frequency value assigned to it just for the sake of easiness but as one might imagine, there is a stumbling block in form of the T constant.

The solution I am looking at now is to simply use a lowercase symbol instead of upper case T, however I am wondering if there would be a quick and easy way to verify if the symbol at hand is T.

All I can think of is:

(intern (if (string= "T" (symbol-name symbol)) #\t symbol)

but that just does not look nice since string comparison is not cumbersome. Any ideas?

PS. I need all the symbols in upper case since it is less hassle to evaluate them in listener but I can live with one lowercase t.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `T`?

Comment: I am not trying to avoid it, in fact I would like to use it but at the current state of Lisp development I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may `shadow` the symbol `T`:

```
CL-USER> (shadow 't)
COMMON-LISP:T
CL-USER> (let ((t 17)) t)
17
```

The shadowed constant `T` may still be referred to as `cl:t`.

Comment: Yep, that definitely does the trick but I probably will be doing that in an empty package and it is going to be ideal.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a [hash](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html#hash-tables) [table](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_.htm) instead of hacking the current package into an ad-hoc one. It sidesteps the T issue entirely, and is a far cleaner solution.

If concision is a concern, you can have a function like `(defun frequency (char) (gethash char the-table))`, which you ought to use even in the main body of code, since aside from being shorter it means your code is written in terms of "frequencies of characters" rather than in terms of "looking up values in a hash table."

If you're looking for the ultimate in keyboarding minimalism for the REPL, you can go so far as to define a reader macro such as:

```
(set-macro-character #\?
                     (lambda (stream char)
                       (declare (ignore char))
                       (let ((char (read stream)))
                         `(frequency (character ',char))))
                     t)
```

Which I guess you might not understand wholly, but nevertheless you can inspect the frequency of #\A with something as simple as `?A`.

Anyways, the point is to write code that accomplishes its objectives simply, perspicuously, and aligned to good style and "best practises," because if you desire something special-purpose like less-typing-in-the-REPL you can always pile on another abstraction layer.

Comment: I sort of know that, but again, for REPL purposes that is just even more cumbersome, ie. writing (gethash symbol table) each time. Simplicity when interrogating code is what I am after here.

Comment: @Werdok: If this is for use in the REPL, why not just make a function that takes table and defines a simple function (f symbol) to (gethash symbol table)? A mix of schemey-lispy syntax `(define (make-easy table) (define (f symbol) (gethash symbol table)))` provided that f could be bound in the appropriate scope.

Comment: I just realized that if you didn't need to swap in and out of a given table context (say, when analyzing many files), that you don't need a lot of what I just wrote. And since you are currently just using symbols without a table, you probably aren't switching contexts.

Comment: What would be the benefits of using a hash table instead of a spare package?